# android application directly login using saved account credential in android device

Tags: android, settings, google-oauth

I want, When i install my app which is directly login using saved gmail credential which is stored in Setting->accounts and sync.How it is possible it has any good tutorial.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is an in-depth look into how you can authenticate based on the users Android credentials, has an example of how things work and how the UI should be [try this](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2)

use some refrence api also available [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android)

You can get help from android developer blog  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html)

Answer (score 0):

After all surfing for answer for this question i have found great tutorial for start to end 
implementation. click [here](http://www.johnermis.com/android-accountmanager-authorization-for-google-api-tutorial/)